# Issue with fstab on Ubuntu14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, smb

I know this has been asked before, but I think somehow I'm in a unique situation since none of the previous solutions I have found have worked for me. 
I'm trying to connect to a smb share on a nas on with the address of 192.168.2.2 with a share at /volume1/Matt but for the life of me I can't get it to work.
I can connect to the share through the file manager by clicking on connect to server and entering smb://192.168.2.2/ and then entering credentials.

I have trying variations of changing the fstab including

//192.168.2.2/volume1/Matt /media/synology cifs credentials=/home/ubuntu/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0

the same but with //192.168.2.2 or //192.168.2.2/volume1 and all variations including and not including a ending slash.

the same as above with the credentials typed in with username=XXXX,pass=XXXX
mounting directly using mount -t

Something that might be of note is that this ubuntu machine is on a vm and it's subnet is 192.168.1.0. I'm not sure why that would matter since I'm able to connect to the smb share through the file manager, but at this point I'm really not sure what the issue

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Most of NAS want you to pass the DOMAIN with the username, like `**username=DOMAIN\\user,password=yourpassword**`.

Remember that is really necessary to use the slashes.